# What is the best way to provide the LuisRecognizer with predetermined textual context other than ITurnContext RecognizeAsync derived from user input?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

My first idea to complete a luis call would be to either set the turnContext but most of its properties are readonly.  As well I would know how to create an exact context that would be created from a user input, mainly the text they put in providing the context needed to pass through to the LuisRecognizer.

My second idea is from the waterfallstep that is calling the LuisHelper(stepContext.Context) is to set this manually as well.  You can't because it too is read only and so is stepContext.Result...

So my question becomes is there a way to feed the luisRecognizer a phrase of text that can be appended to the user's answer.

Example... If I ask user what color car are you looking for.  I know my intent is CarColor so if users says... Blue then I want to append to that statement Customer would like a car color of Blue... so that I can abstract out the entity which would be blue and know that I am referring to an intent of CarColor.  Just be clear on why I want to do this.

What would be a way that I can take a users response and append text to it and then send that as the phrase to the LuisRecognizer call.

here is some code for reference:

```
     private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                stepContext.Values["tester"] = "Travel to Chicago";

                stepContext.Result = "christian";

                // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt.)
                var bookingDetails = stepContext.Result != null
                        ?
                    await LuisHelper.ExecuteLuisQuery(Configuration, Logger, stepContext.Context, cancellationToken)
                        :
                    new BookingDetails();

                // In this sample we only have a single Intent we are concerned with. However, typically a scenario
                // will have multiple different Intents each corresponding to starting a different child Dialog.

                // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), bookingDetails, cancellationToken);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to**

You should be able to achieve this by setting the `Text` property of the `Activity` which is under the `Context` property like so:

```
stepContext.Context.Activity.Text = "The phrase that you want to pass through here";
```

Do this assignment *BEFORE* you call `LuisHelper.ExecuteLuisQuery` otherwise your updated `Text` value won't be sent through.

---

**Why this should work**

Since `LuisHelper.ExecuteLuisQuery(Configuration, Logger, stepContext.Context, cancellationToken)` passes through `stepContext.Context` and under the scenes [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/LuisHelper.cs#L33) this context is passed into the `RecognizeAsync` call inside of the `ExecuteLuisQuery` method. Furthermore the `recognizer` variable is of type `LuisRecognizer`, the source code for this class is available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/2e0f146cf6da18f5b828f820fb218742e98a9dcf/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS/LuisRecognizer.cs). The line that you are interested in is [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/2e0f146cf6da18f5b828f820fb218742e98a9dcf/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS/LuisRecognizer.cs#L334) which shows the `Text` property of the `turnContext` being used as the utterance which is passed through.

---

**Source code explanation/Extra info**

For future reference (incase the code or links change) a simplified version of the source code is:

```
public virtual async Task<RecognizerResult> RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await RecognizeInternalAsync(turnContext, null, null, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

where `RecognizeInteralAsync` looks like:

```
private async Task<RecognizerResult> RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, LuisPredictionOptions predictionOptions, Dictionary<string, string> telemetryProperties, Dictionary<string, double> telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var luisPredictionOptions = predictionOptions == null ? _options : MergeDefaultOptionsWithProvidedOptions(_options, predictionOptions);

    BotAssert.ContextNotNull(turnContext);

    if (turnContext.Activity.Type != ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // !! THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE !!
    var utterance = turnContext.Activity?.AsMessageActivity()?.Text;
    RecognizerResult recognizerResult;
    LuisResult luisResult = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(utterance))
    {
        recognizerResult = new RecognizerResult
        {
            Text = utterance,
            Intents = new Dictionary<string, IntentScore>() { { string.Empty, new IntentScore() { Score = 1.0 } } },
            Entities = new JObject(),
        };
    }
    else
    {
        luisResult = await _runtime.Prediction.ResolveAsync(
            _application.ApplicationId,
            utterance,
            timezoneOffset: luisPredictionOptions.TimezoneOffset,
            verbose: luisPredictionOptions.IncludeAllIntents,
            staging: luisPredictionOptions.Staging,
            spellCheck: luisPredictionOptions.SpellCheck,
            bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey: luisPredictionOptions.BingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey,
            log: luisPredictionOptions.Log ?? true,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        recognizerResult = new RecognizerResult
        {
            Text = utterance,
            AlteredText = luisResult.AlteredQuery,
            Intents = LuisUtil.GetIntents(luisResult),
            Entities = LuisUtil.ExtractEntitiesAndMetadata(luisResult.Entities, luisResult.CompositeEntities, luisPredictionOptions.IncludeInstanceData ?? true),
        };
        LuisUtil.AddProperties(luisResult, recognizerResult);
        if (_includeApiResults)
        {
            recognizerResult.Properties.Add("luisResult", luisResult);
        }
    }

    // Log telemetry code
    await OnRecognizerResultAsync(recognizerResult, turnContext, telemetryProperties, telemetryMetrics, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var traceInfo = JObject.FromObject(
        new
        {
            recognizerResult,
            luisModel = new
            {
                ModelID = _application.ApplicationId,
            },
            luisOptions = luisPredictionOptions,
            luisResult,
        });

    await turnContext.TraceActivityAsync("LuisRecognizer", traceInfo, LuisTraceType, LuisTraceLabel, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return recognizerResult;
}
```

Comment: Oh you are AWESOME!!!! thank you sir. I was close Console.WriteLine("hello" + turnContext.Activity = "read"); I put that in but it gave me the read error because it is a class.  Just to ask do you understand why I would want to do this and do you see any better way.  Essentially I will be able to get a purposeful question to return entity even with one word answers. I think it's pretty awesome if not exactly straight forward.

Comment: "What would be a way that I can take a users response and append text to it and then send that as the phrase to the LuisRecognizer call." I'm a little confused as to why you're sending another request off to LUIS if you already have the intent - what is the next step? Maybe if you could explain the overall goal/workflow that you're working through I could suggest something. :-)

Comment: The idea is to allow for single word answers that the application will have context to.  For example, if I ask for a color of a car and a color of a car interior that is inherently 2 different questions begging for a single word answer that may be the same.  For Luis perhaps that doesn't matter as I can boil down the entity across intents as ColorRequest and when a color is given it abstracts it.  However, other single word answers might be inhrently different and need a basis of context.  i.e. how do you feel -> not well.  Do you feel tired -> kinda... How do we process a reverse q and a

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Are there other steps related to customising the car outside of the internal and external colour? I’m leaning towards a ‘GetCarDetails’ intent which would trigger a waterfall dialog in your code to ask the user questions and collect the answers, then end the dialogue once all questions are answered.